How can I calculate the density of moving air
I am experimenting to find a relation between the Coefficient of Power of a Wind Turbine and its Swept Area. To do that, I need to find the change in the air density before and after the air passes through the blades.
Are there any formulas that account for the changes in density due to velocity or any apparatus I can use to measure air density?
